PushNotifications with AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient not able to configure TTL for Android
Update
When I use the legacy time_to_live parameter instead of the ttl parameter then it does work. For more information about this see What's the difference between `ttl` and `time_to_live` property in FCM message for android push?
My current working Message is:
Message = $"{\"GCM\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\":{data}, \\\"ttl\\\":\\\"0s\\\", \\\"time_to_live\\\": 0 }\" }";

Then the questions I have are:

Why does AWS only support the legacy time_to_live instead of the ttl?
Is it a good idea to set them both like what Im currently doing?
And Why is the AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL not working? According to the documentation it should always take precedence over whatever is the message itself. Did I use an incorrect value then?

Original question:
For sending pushnotifications I am using AWS SNS which works quite well.
I am now trying to configure a 'time to live' of 0 for push notifications.
This because I only want the push message when the app is able to process it immediately.
Currently I am using this C# snippet (Running in an Azure App Service). Push notifications do arrive but it's not respecting the TTL:
var data = JsonHelper.SerializeIgnoreNull(data).Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
var sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(snsAccessKey, snsAccessSecret);
var data = JsonHelper.SerializeIgnoreNull(data).Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
var publishRequest = new PublishRequest() { 
    TargetArn = arn, 
    Message = $"{\"GCM\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\":{data} }\", \"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL\":0 }", 
    MessageStructure = "json" 
 };
var result = sns.Publish(publishRequest);

When I do something similar for iOS the ttl does work.
For Android I also tried a couple of other constructions of the Message property:
Including a ttl property inside the GCM object
Message = $"{\"GCM\\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\”{data}, \\\"ttl\\\": 0 }\", \"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL\":0 }", 

The AWS attribute inside the GCM object:
Message = $"{\"GCM\\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\":{data}, \\\"ttl\\\": 0, \\\"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL\\\":0 }\"}", 

Both ttl and AWS properties outside the GCM object:
Message = $"{\"GCM\\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\":{data} }\", \"ttl\": 0, \"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL\":0 }", 

I alsy tried setting just the ttl with the string 0s
Message = $"{\"GCM\": \"{\\\"priority\\\": \\\"high\\\", \\\"data\\\":{data} , \\\"ttl\\\":\\\"0s\\\" }\" }";

I also tried setting the AWS attributes using the MessageAttributes on the object:
Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue> attributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();
attributes.Add("AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "0", DataType = "Number" });
publishRequest.MessageAttributes = attributes;

When I look at the documentation I would think I should use the attributes or the first version of this post. See AWS SNS TTL Documentation
